# how to create sub column of a field in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

i have a table in which i have a field named Work_Type_Name in this field again some work_Type  has sub_work_Name like column name is
"Civil_work"  and in this work type there are:
road construction,
Bridge Construction,
pond Construction, and few more column are there.

like this there are more fields which are having sub column.

**my question is that how to create this type of table which is having this type of structure.**
 pl.help me.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You could create another table called `Work_Type` with definition

```
Work_type_id  Work_type_name  parent_id
------------  --------------  ---------
```

then you can store all the work type in this table with `parent_id` referring to `work_type_id` of the same table.

If there is no parent for a work type you can store `0` as `parent_id`.

Ex:

```
Work_type_id Work_type_name       parent_id
------------ -------------------  ---------
1            Civil_work           0
2            road construction    1
3            bridge construction  1
```

Finally, you can change the `Work_Type_Name` in the original table to `Work_type_id`.